# How do I get VC++ to auto generate thin smart pointer wrappers for a COM object?

Tags: visual-c++, com, dllimport

I'm trying to import a COM interface into VC++.  The COM object is from a application called IDEA, but as that is not very easy to get a hold of for others to help me. So I figure that if someone could give me instructions as to how I would do this for Word, it would be equivalent.

IDEA does have a .tlb file, but it would appear that it is incomplete.  I can access the COM API using python with an example being something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dbName = "Sample-Employees.IMD"
    idea = win32ComClient.Dispatch(dispatch="Idea.IdeaClient")
    db = idea.OpenDatabase(dbName) # open db
    table_def = db.TableDef()      # get table definition
```

Using the .tbl file, I can get as far as this:

```
#import "D:\Program Files (x86)\CaseWare IDEA\IDEA\Idea.tlb" 
#include "x64\Debug\idea.tlh"
#include "x64\Debug\idea.tli"
void fn()
{
    Idea::IIdeaClientPtr client;
    auto db = client->OpenDatabase("Sample-Employees.IMD");
    db-> // interface not defined
}
```

Intellisense will complete after the `db->` with the following: `AddRef`, `GetIdOfNames`, `GetTypeInfo`, `GetTypeInfoCount`, `Invoke`, `QueryInterface` and `Release`.  Thus, what I mean by an incomplete interface definition.

Now, since the python example states `Idea.IdeaClient`, and I've seen this with word as well (i.e. `word.application`), I was thinking that it might be possible to use that.  Looking around though, I can't seem to find reference to that using `#import`.  I have seen it being used with `CLSIDFromProgID`, but that is very manual mechanism.  COM SMARTPTRs would be far more preferable.

Is this even possible to do with VC++?

Comment: It may be possible to use what is explained on this page. [How to: Create and Use CComPtr and CComQIPtr Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/how-to-create-and-use-ccomptr-and-ccomqiptr-instances?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Thanks @kunif, but I was trying to find a tool to generate a thin C++ wrapper around the COM object, not only to expose the interface, but to have hard compile time errors if things in the interface were used incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe OpenDatabase returns `IDispatch`, but interface containing `TableDef` is still defined in TLB.
In this case you'll need to downcast `IDispatch` to `I-something-containing-TableDef-method`.

Use `QueryInterface` call to get derived interface from `IDispatch`, not C or C++ casts, such as `static_cast`.

Otherwise, you'll need to use `IDispatch::Invoke`. The best help you have is `CComPtr<IDispatch>` from ATL, this template specialization have Invoke helpers, so that you can do something like this:

```
CComPtr<IDispatch> p;
p = db;
CComVairant result;
p.Invoke("TableDef", &result);
```

Or use IDispatch::Invoke as is.

Python aways relies on `IDispatch::Invoke` and does not use static interfaces, that's why it does not encounter this problem.

Comment: Cool! I'll try it tomorrow and let you know how I made out.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `.tlh` and `.tli` files generated don't contain anything that.  The only COM SMARTPTRs they contain are `IIdea`, `IIdeaClient`, `IIdeaClient2`, `IIdeaClient3`, `IProjectManagement`, `ICommonDialogs`, `ITaskPusher` and `IAudiconHelper`.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting.  I was able to use `#import "progid:Idea.IdeaClient"` and `#import "progid:Idea.TableDef"` and it generated 4 files: `idea.tlh`, `idea.tli`, `comdb.tlh` and `comdb.tli`.  Inside of the `comdb.tlh` there is `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ITableDef, __uuidof(ITableDef))` defined, meaning that `ITableDefPtr` would be as well. One other thing though, although I included the `.tlh` and `.tli` files manually, I get from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp) that I shouldn't have to.  Do you know why this is so?

Comment: There should not be need to include generated files, `#import` directive both generates .tlh /.tli if they need to be (re-)generated and includes them. 

Some prefer to comment out #import directive to avoid generation of these files on each build, then yes, you'll need to include .tlh / .tli manually. But standard flow is still #import and generation of these files each time they need to be generated.

Comment: Assuming you have `ITableDefPtr table_def;` declaration and `auto db = client->OpenDatabase("Sample-Employees.IMD");`  statement, your `QueryInterface` cast may look like this:  `db.QueryInterface ( __uuidof(ITableDef), &table_def);`

Comment: Hmmmmm, turns out that the command `client->OpenDatabase("Sample-Employees.IMD")` doesn't work because the pointer wasn't initialized.  I'm assuming that I have to create the object, but I'm not sure how.  I have a `CoInitialize(nullptr)` call, and now have added `HRESULT hr = client.CreateInstance(__uuidof(IIdeaClient))`, but `hr` says `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`, and I can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

Comment: `client.CreateInstance(__uuidof(IIdeaClient))` is wrong, you should pass *CLSID* (class GUID), not *IID* (interface GUID)

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this.  How do I to get that?

Comment: look for /* coclass */ - marked structs in .tlh, some will have IIdeaClient as implemented interface

Comment: actually, you don't even need CLSID. Pass `"Idea.IdeaClient"` string to `CreateInstance`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187211/discussion-between-adrian-and-alexander-gutenev).